# Failed to load class GuzzleHttp\Client from github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle, ubuntu-server, mail-server, roundcube

I had a problem when I was going to configure roundcube webmail, where I had problems with GuzzleHttp\Client not loading (aka NOT OK) which prevented me from going to the next step

One way that I have done is try to install the library with the command "apt-get install php-guzzlehttp", but the package cannot be located. then I tried using composer to install the library, but the result I got is still the same.

my hope is that GuzzleHttp\Client can be loaded
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MOut.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How did you run composer? you should use `composer require ..` to get it into the composer.json of your project. You also need to include/require composers autoloader afterwards